# Pass single variable to PostAsJsonAsync not object

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, blazor-webassembly

I'm using PutAsJsonAsync in a Blazor WA app.

I can pass objects from client to Server in a hosted app (Server is basically a Web API app)

```
public async Task Pause(int id)
{
    var x = new PartyList
    {
        Psid = id
    };

    var c = await _client.PutAsJsonAsync($"api/party/pause", x);
}


[HttpPut("pause")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Pause(PartyList partyList)
{
    await _partySingerRepository.PauseAsync(partyList.Psid);

    return Ok();
}
```

However I'd like to pass an int instead of a full object

```
public async Task Pause(int id)
{
    var c = await _client.PutAsJsonAsync($"api/party/pause", id);
}


[HttpPut("pause")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Pause(int id)
{
    await _partySingerRepository.PauseAsync(id);

    return Ok();
}
```

However, the server (Web API) method doesn't get hit like this, or if I make id an anonymous type either.

Is it possible to pass in a single int or do I have to create an object?

I couldn't find anything on Google about this.

Thanks

Comment: Does the remote end only accept  an int? Do you have control of the code of the remote end?

Comment: Do you really think you can pass an object but not an int?  Of course not, so you have a code problem.  When you make the call does anything in the controller get hit?  Have you tested with Postman?

Comment: I control all the code - it’s a hostel Blazor WA app

Comment: Looks like the issue is at the controller, not the calling code post the code for api/party/pause

Comment: It seems like the controller wants an object not a primitive?

Answer (score 1):

Just had this same issue myself. Not with one parameter, but with two. It didn't work, not even with an anonymous object, until I created a class to hold the values.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).